# Regex to open links in new window that do not contain "xyz" in hostname using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to add a jQuery check that will launch any links across my site to external websites. How can I do the following:

Look for any anchor links that do not contain "xyz" in the hostname. For example:

- `http://xyz.com`
- `http://asfasdfadsfadsf.xyz.com`

It must ignore any links that contain xyz after the hostname though:

- `http://someothersite.com/xyz`

> ```
> $('a[href^="http://%xyz%"]').filter(function() {
>   return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
> }).attr('target', '_blank');
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!(/https?:\/\/[^\/]*xyz.*/i.test(link))
```

See **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dgy6T/)**.

---

[JSHint](http://www.jshint.com) Example:

```
/*global $:false */

(function() {

  "use strict";

  $('a').filter(function() {
    return !(/https?:\/\/[^\/]*xyz.*/i.test($(this).attr('href')));
  }).text("***");

}());
```

Comment: Thanks. It's causing an error in my JS and it's not working for me. If I paste your code into jshint.com, it comes up with "Unexpected '​'.". Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: @Cofey - It shold work in your JS, if you load jQuery and put the code to proper place. Regarding JSHint - you probably don't know how to use this tool - I have updated my answer with JSHint example, so you can test it. Do not forget to turn on "jQuery" in option list.

Comment: Thanks again. I see your code isn't generating any errors inside the self encapsulating function. When I add it into my namespace though, it does. See my update above to your post.

Comment: @Cofey - I am sorry, but your JSHint issue is beyond your original question. I suggest you to submit new question regarding proper syntax of namescape functions...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to get all the anchors links and go through each `href` applying this regex `(?:xyz.)`. If the regex exist that means that URL is bad, push everything else into and array and then do whatever your want with them.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it.  There are probably some optimizations you can do:

```
$("a").each(function(idx, link) {
    var href = link.href;
    if (!href) {return;}
    href = href.split("//");
    if (href.length < 2) {return;}
    href = href[1];
    var index = href.indexOf("/");
    if (index > -1) {
        href = href.substring(0, index);
    }
    if (!/\bxyz\b/g.test(href)) {
        link.target = "_blank";
    }
});
```